# uninitialized constant Store rails routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Store controller and an Items controller, I want each item to appear under store/ as store/items/id, my routes file is;

```
match 'store'=> 'store#index'

namespace :store do
   resources :items, only: [:show]
end
```

when I link to an item on the store page I get the correct url e.g 'store/items/1' but when I follow the link I get the error

> ActionController::RoutingError at /store/items/1
>   uninitialized constant Store

I don't know why I'm getting this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`namespace` rolls up *module*, *name prefix* and *path prefix*.

But in your case, you don't have a module named `Store`. It is a controller instead. That is, it is looking for `Store::ItemsController`.

Use this instead:

```
scope '/store' do
  resources :items, only: [:show]
end
```

This will give you the path such as `item_path` and URI like `/store/items/1`

Comment: ok, so how do I write my route properly without using namespace?

Comment: Added above. See if this is what you want. :)